# How to feedback via email in Rate My App Windows Phone 8 ?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I use library "Rate My App" by Nokia Developer.
Link : http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/code-examples/rate-my-app.html
How to feedback via email (give feedback) in Windows Phone 8?

Help me ! Thank ...

Comment: If you are looking for a method to send e-mila, [the MSDN will help you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394003(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: is the feedback not working in RateMyApp??